# How to share a document in Google Drive in VB or C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, google-drive-api

I want to share a document using the Goole Drive Api. Once I get a list of documents I don't know how to share a document with one or more users.

**EDIT:**

```
 Dim files As FileList = request.Fetch()
 Dim oPermission As New Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.Permission
 oPermission.Role = "reader"
 oPermission.Type = "user"
 oPermission.Value = "something@gmail.com"
 Dim oPermissionResource As New Google.Apis.Drive.v2.PermissionsResource(service, auth)

     For Each oFile As Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File In files.Items

            service.Permissions.Insert(oPermission, oFile.Id).Fetch()
     Next
```

As @Ramhound pointed I was going the right way, I changed the code as in the example provided by @Ali Afshar. Now I'm getting an error:

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Internal Error [500]
Errors [
    Message[Internal Error] Location[ - ] Reason[internalError] Domain[global]
]
```

**EDIT 2:**

The error occurs when I set the permission role as *owner*. If i use other roles like *reader*, *writer*. The example works fine.

```
 oPermission.Role = "owner" 'an error occurs
```

Does someone know what can cause the error in the example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are indeed right.  Go ahead and try it and then post your attempt.  Post the important sections from the Google Drive API once you do.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was a bit confused between the update and insert method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `permissions.insert` method, there is an example for .Net in our [examples section](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert#examples) for that method.

Comment: I followed your example and I get an error, do you know what can cause this error? Thanks for your reply!