# Share a document with specified user in Google Drive

Tags: vb.net, google-drive-api

I want to share a file that exists in Google Drive with a specified user. The file is not public.

Firstly, I want to show a file in a WebBrowser control. 
Secondly, I want that when I share an URL to a different user, they can then show the file in their Google Drive.

Here is my code, I already can do the first step but for the second step, I don't know how I can do it.

```
Public Sub A(fichier As String)
 CreateService()
    Dim url As String = ""
    Dim list = Service.Files.List()
    Dim count = list.Execute()
    For Each fich In count.Items
        If (fich.Title) = fichier Then
            url = fich.WebContentLink
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    affich_image.img.Navigate(url)
    affich_image.Show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `permissions.insert` method.

> Inserts a permission for a file or Team Drive.

To see the parameters and further details, try to visit the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert).

Here, I provide you the sample code for .NET that was introduced in the said documentation.

```
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data;

using System.Net;
// ...

public class MyClass {

  // ...

  /// <summary>
  /// Insert a new permission.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="service">Drive API service instance.</param>
  /// <param name="fileId">ID of the file to insert permission for.</param>
  /// <param name="value">
  /// User or group e-mail address, domain name or null for "default" type.
  /// </param>
  /// <param name="type">The value "user", "group", "domain" or "default".</param>
  /// <param name="role">The value "owner", "writer" or "reader".</param>
  /// <returns>The inserted permission, null is returned if an API error occurred</returns>
  public static Permission InsertPermission(DriveService service, String fileId, String value,
      String type, String role) {
    Permission newPermission = new Permission();
    newPermission.Value = value;
    newPermission.Type = type;
    newPermission.Role = role;
    try {
      return service.Permissions.Insert(newPermission, fileId).Execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
    }
    return null;
  }

  // ...

}
```

You may also visit this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262498/how-to-share-a-document-in-google-drive-in-vb-or-c-sharp) for further discussion.